# Create a matrix out of table using awk

Tags: matrix, awk

I want to use this table:

```
a   16  moe max us
b   11  tom mic us
d   14  roe fox au
t   29  ann teo au
n   28  joe joe ca
```

and make this matrix by using awk (or any other simple option in bash):

```
    a_16;   b_11;   d_14;   t_29;   n_28
us; moe_max;    tom_mic;    ;   ;       
au; ;   ;   roe_fox;    ann_teo;    
ca; ;   ;   ;   ;   joe_joe
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
awk '{a[$5]=a[$5]?a[$5] FS $1"_"$2:$1"_"$2; b[$5]=b[$5]?b[$5] FS $3"_"$4:$3"_"$4;} END{for (i in a){print i"\t" a[i] "\t" b[i];}}' fis.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any `awk`

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    row           = $NF
    col           = $1 "_" $2
    vals[row,col] = $3 "_" $4
}

!seenRow[row]++ { rows[++numRows] = row }
!seenCol[col]++ { cols[++numCols] = col }

END {
    OFS = ";  "

    printf "     "
    for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
        col = cols[colNr]
        printf "%s%s", col, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        row = rows[rowNr]
        printf "%s%s", row, OFS
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            col = cols[colNr]
            #val = ((row,col) in vals ? vals[row,col] : "  ")
            val = vals[row,col]
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
     a_16;  b_11;  d_14;  t_29;  n_28
us;  moe_max;  tom_mic;  ;  ;
au;  ;  ;  roe_fox;  ann_teo;
ca;  ;  ;  ;  ;  joe_joe
```

I can't see the pattern in the expected output in your question of when there should be 1, 2, 3, or 4 spaces after each `;` so I just used a consistent 2 in the above. Massage it to suit.

Comment: ; is just a FS, There shouldn't be any space

Comment: Don't put characters in the input or output in your question that you don't want us to use in our answers as that's just wasting everyones' time and making it harder for us to help you. I for one spent more time trying to figure out the logic behind the spaces after each `;` than any other part of your question and after my first attempt someone pointed out I got it wrong and had to re-do it, again just because of those spaces you're now saying shouldn't even be there. Edit your question to show what your input and output should really look like.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk` multidimensional arrays for collecting header columns and row indices:

```
awk '{
    head[NR] = $1"_"$2;
    idx[$5][NR] = $3"_"$4
}
END {
    h = ""; col_size = length(head);
    for (i = 1; i <= col_size; i++) {
        h = sprintf("%s  %s", h, head[i])
    }
    print h;
    for (lab in idx) {
        printf("%s", lab);
        for (i = 1; i <= col_size; i++) {
            v = sprintf("%s;  %s", v, idx[lab][i])
        }
        print v;
        v = "";
    }
}' test.txt
```

---

```
  a_16  b_11  d_14  t_29  n_28
ca;  ;  ;  ;  ;  joe_joe
au;  ;  ;  roe_fox;  ann_teo;  
us;  moe_max;  tom_mic;  ;  ;
```

Comment: ; is a FS, how can I add it to the header row too? and can empty values be empty instead of spaces?

Comment: @Dr.HeinzDoofenshmirtzPhD, add semicolon to the line as shown `h = sprintf("%s  %s;", h, head[i])`

Comment: And how can write the fields as empty instead of one space?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby to do that:

```
ruby -e 'd=$<.read.
    split(/\R/).
    map(&:split).
    map{|sa| sa.each_slice(2).map{|ss| ss.join("_") } }.
    group_by{|sa| sa[-1] }

# {"us"=>[["a_16", "moe_max", "us"], ["b_11", "tom_mic", "us"]], "au"=>[["d_14", "roe_fox", "au"], ["t_29", "ann_teo", "au"]], "ca"=>[["n_28", "joe_joe", "ca"]]}

heads=d.values.flatten(1).map{|sa| sa[0]}
# ["a_16", "b_11", "d_14", "t_29", "n_28"]

hsh=Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = ["\t"]*heads.length}
d.each{|k,v| 
    v.each{|sa| 
        hsh[k][heads.index(sa[0])]="\t#{sa[1]}"
    }
}
puts heads.map{|e| "\t#{e}" }.join(";")
hsh.each{|k,v| puts "#{k};\t#{v.join(";")}"}
' file
```

Prints:

```
    a_16;   b_11;   d_14;   t_29;   n_28
us;     moe_max;    tom_mic;    ;   ;   
au;     ;   ;   roe_fox;    ann_teo;    
ca;     ;   ;   ;   ;   joe_joe
```